# Responsive images with image-aligned captions

Tags: css, responsive

For a long time I've been using  to deliver images with design control. I then use CSS to hide or not the specific images within the  block.

Now I'd like to use  with  for more flexibility and control.

My problem is with the caption. I would like to align my caption relative to the image, as I can do with , rather than within it's container div. At the moment my caption can only be aligned as the container is aligned. If the image is centred the caption is centred if the right-aligned the caption is right-aligned. What I could do with , and I'm trying to figure out how to do independantly, is have my image centred on the page and my caption right-aligned relative to the image. Confusing?

Here's an example of what I'm working with at the moment:

```css
    div.dImage {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto 2% auto;
    }

    div.dCaption {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 2% 0 0;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      line-height: 1.2em;
      font-style: italic;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dImage">
    <picture>
        <source srcset="https://picsum.photos/200/300" media="(min-width: 1025px)" />
        <source srcset="https://picsum.photos/200/300" media="(min-width: 800px)" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Image Title Here">
    </picture>
    <div class="dCaption">
        Image Caption Here
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be most appreciated. I can create a Codepen if it would be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below solution.

```css
div.dImage {
  text-align: center;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

div.dCaption {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 2% 0 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="dImage">
<picture>
    <source srcset="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" media="(min-width: 1025px)" />
    <source srcset="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" media="(min-width: 800px)" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300" alt="Image Title Here">
</picture>
<div class="dCaption">
    Image Caption Here
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: image width: maxi-content; is exactly what I needed.

Thank you.